# update ui from a timer swift

Tags: swift, button, ui

Есть программка небольшая, я хочу добавить таймер чтобы оно показывала мне весь мой UI(кнопка созданная программно) на пару секунд в самом начале а потом исчезало. Вопрос как передать данные UI (в func preResult)в таймер?

Часть кода:

```
@objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton!) { 

print("button tapped", "x: \((sender.frame.origin.x)/50) y:((sender.frame.origin.y)/50) ")

let typeField = arr[Int((sender.frame.origin.x)/50) - 1 [Int((sender.frame.origin.y)/50) - 1]
        print(typeField.type)


        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.preResult), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        switch typeField.type {
        case .mine:
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        case .empty:
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        }

        if typeField.typeHidden == .hidden {
            typeField.typeHidden = .notHidden
        }
    }
@objc func preResult(timer: Timer){
        for i in 0...arr.count - 1 {
            for j in 0...arr[i].count - 1 {
                let field: Field = arr[i][j]
            }

      // надо передать ui(данные кнопки)


        }
    }
```

Comment: что значит "передать в таймер"?

Comment: Никак, это селектор. Вам придётся сохранить эту кнопку как свойство класса, а затем в таймере обращаться к ней и делать что хотели (не забудьте обернуть в `DispatchQueue.mayn.async` ибо любые изменения с UI должны происходить в главном потоке)